# Can we tile the board by L trominos?

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

I tried to cover this, but there is no way I can fill it. 
The black square is a removed square.

Is there a way to prove that it cannot be filled with L trominos?

Comment: L shaped using three squares= L tromino

Comment: There are only $24$ squares.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We color each square at $i$-th row and $j$-row with both $i,j$ odd with red paint. Now the $9$ red squares needs $9$ L trominos to be covered. On the other hand, to cover the $5^2-1=24$ squares we need $24/3=8$ L trominos. Contradiction!

[image]

Comment: Your answer is very good! How can you think of this?

Comment: (+1) I had already solved this problem moths ago, but by considering lots of possible cases. This is a great approach.

Comment: Wow, thanks :) nice +1

Comment: @CulverKwan Coloring in Tiling problem is quite common: see for example https://pregatirematematicaolimpiadejuniori.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/lesson_4.pdf